# How large and compact could a cold east Mongolia-like steppe be on an Earth-sized planet?

Tags: planets, earth-like, geography, climate

Welcome to planet X! Planet X is the same as Earth in radius, composition, axial tilt and orbits star Y (identical to the Sun). Planet X has a moon known as moon Z (identical to Earth's moon).

Could an east Mongolia-like region (Köppen BSk) exist on planet X meeting all of the following requirements?

- At least 4 million sq. km. of contiguous Köppen BSk/BWk climate type (preferably 5 million sq. km.)
- Relatively compact (not a long, narrow strip of BSk/BWk climate type)
- Occasional plateaus with colder weather (Köppen Dwb/Dwc) on top

You may do anything with planet X as long as it meets this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the Pleistocene Mammoth Steppe between Europe, across Beringia, and into North America dry/cold enough? While it was not a desert per se, it  was a vast treeless grassland in the arid  Arctic, bordered by continental scale  ice sheets, meaning that it was both  drier and colder  than  modern  day North America/Eurasia. It's a little unclear from your question what level of vegetation is allowed.
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mammoth_steppe

> During the Last Glacial Maximum, the mammoth steppe was the Earth’s most
>   extensive biome. It spanned from Spain eastwards across Eurasia to
>   Canada and from the arctic islands southwards to China.
>   It had a cold, dry climate; the vegetation was dominated by
>   palatable high-productivity grasses, herbs and willow shrubs,
>   and the animal biomass was dominated by bison, horses, and woolly
>   mammoth. This ecosystem covered wide areas of the northern part of
>   the globe, thrived for approximately 100,000 years without major
>   changes, and then suddenly became all but extinct about 12,000 years
>   ago.

You could make it colder/ drier with more mountain uplift,  causing drawdown of  more  atmospheric  CO2.

Comment: It's good that you included a link to the mammoth steppe article, but it would be helpfull if you were to include details of what's on the other end of the link in the body of your answer, as links get broken and we expect answers to stand for themselves.

Comment: Hello Julian, welcome to worldbuilding SE. Your answer is good, but it relies too much on the link you provided, meaning that should the link go down, so will the value of your answer. It'd be best for everyone if you edited your answer as to add the main concepts present in the link, which show why did you choose to add it in the first place.